# How do I prevent jsTree from rendering checkboxes on all but leaf nodes?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I have a request to only have the leaf nodes of the tree have the option of being selected.

This tree is being populated with the json_data plugin. Is there an option available either in the data or through the api to remove checkboxes or prevent them from being rendered?

Answer (score 0):

Which plug-in you use?
There is a lot of plug-ins - here is one so may serve you needs

http://www.greepit.com/2009/03/javascript-dynamic-tree-view-control-for-jquery/

Comment: we are using jsTree. It is built into several other areas of the app. This is the first time that the requirement has come up for this kind of manipulation.